# Which table in Magento 2.3.4 to look for if I need to update the options for Migration_Design attribute

Tags: magento2.3.4, data-migration-tool

which table in Magento 2.3.4 to look for if I need to edit the options for Migration_Design attribute. All I want to do is to ensure the value for Custom Layout Update is only 'No Update' displayed without "Use Existing" dropdown option. If there are alternatives, I shall also be interested. Please refer the image below to see what I am looking to do for each product.

[image]

Comment: table is catalog_product_entity_varchar

Comment: @ Yash Patadia, found it. I would accept if you convert your response to an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Frist the you are goes to database and run the this query

```
SELECT * from catalog_product_entity_varchar
```

And showing all result Please check Screen short :-

**https://prnt.sc/rhpy9e**

Any query let me know...

Comment: sure, will do. It is fine as of now